# How to set @Input variable as an optional in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-decorator

I want to set @Input parameters optional.

For example:

Child1.html:

```
templateUrl:'common-html.html'
```

Child1.TS:

```
currentValue : boolean = true;
```

CASE 2:

Child2.html:

```
templateUrl:'common-html.html'
```

Child2.TS:

```
// Not declared **currentValue**
```

Common-HTML.html:

```
<app-master [isLogEnabled]="currentValue"></app-master>
```

But above changes giving an error while AOT:

> Property 'isLogEnabled' does not exist on type Child2.Component

So I cannot change HTML of :

```
<app-master [isLogEnabled]="currentValue"></app-master>
```

Comment: You cannot do `<app-master></app-master>`?

Comment: Actually, that HTML is used as a centralized, so I cannot change

Comment: The question is unclear at the moment. But answering the question of "optional input properties", you could try `isLogEnabled?: any` in the child component.

Comment: Added more info

Comment: Probably not as clean, but you could pass an object instead, with optional properties.

Comment: @David example?

Comment: @MichaelD I tried but it shows same error

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

App-Master-Component.ts

```
@Input() isLogEnabled: boolean = false; // can change false to true, null or w.e. depending on what you want as the default
// if consumer passes in a value, it will be overridden
```

Then in Child2.component.html

```
<app-master></app-master>
```

You cannot bind `[isLogEnabled]="currentValue"` if currentValue does not exist in the Child2.component.ts file.

Comment: The HTML is common so I can not change the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can't provide property that you didn't declare.
But you can use something like this:

```
<app-master [isLogEnabled]="currentValue || false"></app-master>
```

Or inside component you can create getter:

```
get isLogEnabled() {
    return this.isLogEnabled || false;
}
```

Or you can try to use **'?'**

```
@Input() isLogEnabled?: boolean;
```